# How to use .pub file to create ssh season

Tags: ssh, putty

I have received a .pub file and I want to connect to the server using the ssh connection .
How can I use it in putty or another ssh programs?

Answer (score -2):

Please check this link: https://library.linode.com/security/ssh-keys

In short, you need to copy the .pub key on remote host. For that purpose you need to use an account which DOES have SSH access to the remote host.

Beside, you also need to have the private key which will be used in handshake with the public key that you will be copying on the remote host.

Read the above referred link carefully and you will learn fairly easily how this can be done.